# SharePoint 2010 Foundation vs Enterprise Security Vulnerability Patch

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, patching

We have a little confusion here as to which security patches we should be applying to our SharePoint 2010 Enterprise farm.
The following states there is a patch for Foundation Server, but nothing for Enterprise 2010 Server.  Why is this?   Is the security patch covered elsewhere?  Where?

https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2019-1260/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you apply the [SharePoint Server 2010 September 2019 CU](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4475603/september-10-2019-cumulative-update-for-sharepoint-server-2010-kb44756), it will cover all the security fix (CVE-2019-1257,CVE-2019-1260, CVE-2019-1295).

You have SharePoint server then it is advisable to install the server cu which include the [foundation cu as well](https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2019/09/11/september-2019-cu-for-sharepoint-2010-product-family-is-available-for-download/).

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a reason why there is no specific HotFix - type patch for this though?  Seems odd to me there is no specific one for it being a security vulnerabilty